# Requirements for $\mathbf Q = \mathbf P\cdot\mathbf Q^T\cdot\mathbf P^T$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Say I have a known matrix $\mathbf Q$, outer product of 2 vectors. What kind of matrix $\mathbf P$ do I need for the following statement to be true?

$$\mathbf Q = \mathbf P\cdot\mathbf Q^T\cdot\mathbf P^T$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this means $Q$ is of rank one, in that case this question might have been answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704238/singular-value-decomposition-of-rank-1-matrix